# Python: Enable custom object to be multiplied with / added to a standard type

Tags: python

I know that it is possible to create a [`object.__mul__(self, other)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__) method to enable the custom multiplication of two objects. However, as explained in the python docs,

> to evaluate the expression `x + y`, where `x` is an instance of a class
>   that has an `__add__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` is called.

Is it possible in any way to allow for the custom multiplication / addition of objects in the reversed order, i.e. `y + x`, where `x` is an instance we have control over, and `y` is of a standard type, e.g. a float?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

And in fact, it's explained just half a page down in the same docs you were looking at. You just define an [`__rmul__(self, other)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) method.

As the docs say:

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `divmod()`, `pow()`, `**`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|`) with reflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the expression `x - y`, where *y* is an instance of a class that has an `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`.

So:

```
>>> class Thingy(object):
...     def __mul__(self, other):
...         print('mul', other)
...     def __rmul__(self, other):
...         print('rmul', other)
>>> thingy = Thingy()
>>> thingy * 3
mul 3
>>> 3 * thingy
rmul 3
```

See the Note about subclasses if it's relevant; for builtin types, usually it isn't.

Also notice that there's no `__rlt__`, `__req__`, etc., but the same rules apply; it's just that the reflections are the `__gt__`, `__eq__`, etc. methods you already defined.